# Trying to fetch a field in a row using foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a simple script that goes over a file (name list) and would use each line (name) to produce an sql query to fetch the id of that name.

```
$linearray = explode("|", file_get_contents('designer.txt'));
foreach ($linearray as $line) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE slug = '{$line}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['term_id'];

}
```

Now, for some reason I only get the last word `term_id`. Although if I try to echo the line, it works.

Any idea why the sql is being execute only at the last line?

Comment: How `designer.txt` is formatted?

Comment: And why do you use the pipe `'|'` as delimiter in `explode()`? Shouldn't you use `\n` (or `\r\n` for Windows text files)? What's the output of `print_r($linearray);`?

Comment: woop. didn't notice that, I took that line from another code I did for a file that contains | as space. I feel such a noob :) Cheers for noticing me, thats done the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Ok :) However, read what GordonM said to you.

Comment: There should not be any double quotes (") inside the designer.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever execute SQL queries in a loop!  An SQL query is an expensive operation and you should keep them to a minimum.  You're much better off building the query to fetch all the data in one go.

```
$lineArray = array_filter ($lineArray, 'mysql_real_escape_string'); // Protect against SQL injection
$slugList = implode (', ', $lineArray);
$sql = 'SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE slug IN (' . $slugList . ')';

if ($result = mysql_query ($sql))
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
    {
        var_dump ($row);
    }
}
```